# Cannot Display Image from List

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to display `ListItems` in a `GridView`.

I am able to access the list items but my image is getting displayed as url .

I am using:

```
dr["Category"] = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(oListItem["Category"]));
```

The above line of code displays the list items, but when I try to display the images, it renders as `http://server/images/xyz.jpg` in the gridview.

Please help me in accessing the list images.

**Update:**

With regard to [Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837852/cannot-display-image-from-list/837932#837932):

I have tried this:

```
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems) {
    dr["Category"] = 
         SPEncode.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(oListItem["Category"]));
}
```

But when i try to display the images:

```
dr["ProductImage"] = 
       SPEncode.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(oListItem["ProductImage"]));
```

It still renders as: `http://server/images/xyz.jpg` in the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

This question could use a few more details. It would help to know what oListItem[key] and dr[key] were arrays of. Whatever it is, it looks like `oListItem[].ToString()` method just returns a URL.

Couldn't you just new up an Image control, set the ImageSrc propery, and then add it into the GridView? You need to instantiate a new Image with each row (don't reuse an Image).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ASP.NET GridView?
In that case you can set the filed property to your image column to Image Field.
Then you can assign the value of your converted oListItem["ProductImage"] field to the PictureUrl field.

Here's an example to get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try the solution provided here:

> http://cipriangrosu.blogspot.com/2009/05/display-item-type-icon-in-spgridview.html